# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade has reset keyboard to US, cannot use £ sign in root login or user login

Tags: keyboard, login, keyboard-layout

After upgrading to 18.04 when the Virtual Machine boots it has the US keyboard set. User login and root login both share the £ symbol which is no longer available.

The ubuntu system is being run under VMware 12.

I have tried using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> but the ALT key is not recognised. I've tried <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> but this just produces a # symbol. I've even tried cut and paste between Win 10 and the virtual machine but no dice.

At present I have no access to the VM at all.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you use a liveusb to chnage the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows machine, you are used to compose with Alt+number. Try Ctrl+Shift+u combination. Then, you can write a Unicode hex input, for pound sing it is 'a3'. Confirm with Enter.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and I now have access to my machine.